# how to get spring-data-elasticsearch query full dsl

Tags: opensearch

i use elasticsearchRestTemplate before,but now my project changeto opensearch ,now i want get zhe full dsl from elasticsearchRestTemplate query,the code blow has just get query or filter or any other,how i do

```
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("libId", "aaaa","aaaa"));
        BoolQueryBuilder filter = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("libId", "1570417636662079490","1570417636670468098"));
        NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withFilter(filter)
                .withQuery(queryBuilder)
                .withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("createDate").order(SortOrder.DESC))
                .build();
        String s1 = query.getQuery().toString();
        String s2 = query.getFilter().toString();
        List<Sort.Order> collect = query.getSort().toList();
        Map<String,String> mm = new HashMap<>();
        mm.put("query",s1);
        mm.put("filter",s2);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.